# Winform netsh Process unable to accept multiple arguments

Tags: multithreading, winforms, user-interface, process, worker

This is the first time I am using ProcessStartInfo with multiple arguments and I'm at wits end pulling my hair out to make my code work. I keep getting an error or some version of the following error depending on whether or not or how I use escaping in the arguments string.

I have tried multiple stackoverflow code snippets and read everything I can from MSDN.
MSDN indicates that white spaces should be escaped.  I receive an error when I do that... I also receive an error if I don't escape the arguments.  The following error displays in textBox1.Text...

> [1]: The following command was not found: "trace start capture=yes
>   report=no persistent=no traceFile=C:\temp\mynettrace.etl".

But when I launch it from a `WinForms` `Button` click, it does not like the way I have configured the Arguments.
I consulted the MSDN reference that displays multiple args and I must not be thinking clearly.
What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Remote_Site_Tools
{
    public partial class DegradationCaptureForm : Form
    {
        public StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        public DegradationCaptureForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DegradationCaptureStartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DegradationFunction();
        }

        public void DegradationFunction()
        {
            int lineCount = 0;
            this.textBox1.Text = "";

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "trace start capture=yes report=no persistent=no traceFile=C:\\temp\\mynettrace.etl";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                // Prepend line numbers to each line of the output.
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    lineCount++;
                    output.AppendLine("[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
                }
            });
            process.Start();

            // Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process. 
            // This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();

            // Write the output of the stringbuilder to the textbox
            textBox1.Text = output.ToString();
            process.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you had solved it. There's nothing wrong with this code. It runs correctly. You should verify that the `C:\\temp\\mynettrace.etl` file is not already there, otherwise `netsh` will refuse to overwrite it. Also, stop the trace: `netsh -> trace -> stop` (and delete/move the generated files) before starting another trace with the same file name. Otherwise, `netsh` will refuse to run.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue and was very curious why we were seeing divergent responses - one wherein it wouldn't work, and responses indicating it worked as is. Perhaps I'm a masochist, but I dove into this one and found the answer.

NETSH is a scripting-based shell environment that operates in various *contexts*. The contexts are provided by dependent DLL's that are loaded as each context is established. It occurred to me that not all contexts available in 64-bit NETSH are available in 32-bit NETSH, so I fired up the NETSH in the C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64 folder, and guess what - the "trace start" failed. When I tried the same command in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32, it worked perfectly.

Armed with this information, I spun up a **32-bit** executable firing NETSH - and sure enough - it turns out that it fires from the c:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64 folder - and the "trace start" fails. When I changed the executable to an X64 (64-bit), NETSH was then run out of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 - and guess what - the trace started perfectly, as expected.

It's got to be one of the strangest differences between a 64-bit and a 32-bit app I've seen, but that sure seems to be the answer. You might try to see if you experience the same results in your situation.